# AngularJS - Newbie form validation across multiple fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Firstly apologies if this is a) has been asked before b) a stupid question but I am new to AngularJS and I have a form that I need to add some validation.

I have multiple input fields. For the sake of argument lets call them

client, counterpart and group and initially are all blank.

In english, the rule I am trying to enforce is "If a user enters a group, then either the client or counterpart must be entered. If the user chooses to enter a client, the client should be [a|b|c]"

I am sure that there must be an easy way to achieve this but I am not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Angular validation directives can accept expressions. So, assuming a model:

```
$scope.data = {
    client: "...",
    counterpart: "...",
    group: "..."
};
```

A simple form that does something like what you want would be:

```
<form>
    <input ng-model="data.client" ng-pattern="'(a|b|c)'"
             ng-required="data.group != '' && data.counterpart == ''" />
    <input ng-model="data.counterpart"
             ng-required="data.group != '' && data.client == ''" />
    <input ng-model="data.group" />
</form>
```

(play a bit with the `ng-pattern`)